# Can't get the login function to work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sitting now for like 3 hours at this and I can't solve this problem.

Every time I want to login it says error (no user found).

Here is the login function:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['submit']=="login") {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && checkAnum($_POST['username']) && checkAnum($_POST['password'])) 
    {

      $Cmdlogin = "SELECT * FROM database.account WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND password=PASSWORD('".$_POST['password']."') LIMIT 1";
      $sqllogin = mysqli_query($sqlHp,$Cmdlogin);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($sqllogin)>0)
      {
        $getAdmin = mysqli_fetch_object($sqllogin);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $getAdmin->id;
        $_SESSION["user_username"] = $getAdmin->username;
     }else{echo'error';}
    }
  }
```

And here is the Form:

```
<FORM action="index.php?s=login" method="POST">
                <TD>
                    <TABLE>
                        <TR>
                            <TD align="left">Username</TD>
                            <TD align="left"><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="15"/></TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD align="left">Password</TD>
                            <TD align="left"><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30"/></TD>
                        </TR>
                    </TABLE>
                    <BR>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="login" name="submit" />
</FORM>
```

Does anyone maybe know what is wrong? I don't get it. It really drives me crazy at the moment and stackoverflow is the last hope for me.

**EDIT: I've fixed it. The Length at the password row was set too 30 while the passwords needed more than 30 letters.**

Comment: Do you actually have any users in your database?

Comment: what is this in your query `AND password=PASSWORD('".$_POST['password']."')`

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui `PASSWORD()` is a function in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html

Comment: if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && checkAnum($_POST['username']) && checkAnum($_POST['password'])) 
   this conditions returns true?

Comment: echo your query and run it in `phpmyadmin` to check either your query is working fine or not

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. Ive found out where the problem is at. It looks like something is wrong with AND password=PASSWORD('".$_POST['password']."')

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start();`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $getAdmin->id;
$_SESSION["user_username"] = $getAdmin->username;
```

Comment: Doesn't help. I already have session_start(); inside the index.php file.

Comment: To make sure whether database has records as stated in query. Just print the query statement and copy the query and execute the database query window or  in command prompt.

Comment: Yes, the database has records. Ive also registered more accounts and on Navicat I can see all those accounts.

Comment: add breakpoint in every condition and statment to verify the work flow.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put $_POST at variable

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$Cmdlogin = "SELECT * FROM database.account WHERE username='".$user."' AND password=PASSWORD('" . $pass . "')' LIMIT 1";
```